# pressing on a vertices displays this

Tags: vertices

So I pressed on something by accident and this shows whenever I press on some vertice. It seems to be move option but I don't know how to turn it off.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have enabled a gizmo.

To change or remove it, make the tool bar appear using <kbd>T</kbd>, if not already displayed. Then choose another one or choose the selection box tool.

[image]

Comment: I see, your answer fixed my problem. Thanks.